# How to "connect" cloned element so the changes applied to original are applied to cloned element as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have this situation (it is very simplified for the sake of this question):

```
var original_div = $('<div></div>');
var clone_div = original_div.clone();
original_div.width(300);
```

Is there any way how would automatically get `clone_div` the same width as `original_div` ? I am talking about width, but the solution should work with generally all attributes...

Is this possible ? I would be glad for any hint.

Comment: It'd be easier just to clone it after manipulation

Comment: I can't do that, because the manipulation happens in another place of the script. It's much complicated scenario, I have just simplified it as much as possible..

Comment: you need to add some type of class or something that will `group` these elements together. Clone does not work like this.

Comment: This makes really NO sense: original DIV is a var, NOT an existing DOM element. So it has not yet set ANY width for the CSS property. How you expect to get a width of an element `<div></div>` that is not created? The answer to your current question is: After DIV (var) cloning, and placing, that div will have `width:auto;` (If not differently specified in the CSS from the parent element's ancestors.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I used `<div></div>` only for simplification. In my code, I have actually DOM element. But I want the example in the question to be as simple as possible. Maybe too much simple now :-)

Comment: @Frodik : we like simple examples, but you might simplified it wrongly, or simplified an already buggy script, so I gave you an answer. Halp me understand in depth your question.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks for explanations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new collection of elements that includes both original elements, that way you can modify the collection, and both the original elements will change :

```
var original_div = $('<div></div>');
var clone_div = original_div.clone();
var both_div = original_div.add(clone_div);

both_div.width(300);

console.log(original_div.width());
console.log(clone_div.width());
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gE4SY/)
    ​

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use data() to store a reference against one div to the other, e.g

   original_div.data('clone', clone_div)

then check forth at value whenever you set the width.

1. You could add a class to both the original and the lone, the use that selector to change the width of both.